# Parabolic Question (from Hypatia 2012 Competition)

Tags: conic-sections, integers

I was practicing some questions from the past Waterloo Hypatia competitions, and I came across this question:

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIu33.png)

And upon calculations, I got stuck here:

$$(q+r)(p+q) = -1$$

The [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSFfG.png) claims that either $q + r = 1$ and $p + q = -1$ or $q + r = -1$ and $p + q = 1$, but I don't see why is has to be *those* exact values.

For instance, why can't $q + r = -0.5$ and $p + q = 2$? Integers can still satisfy these conditions, and the product is still -1.

Comment: Because they are assumed to be integers, so $q+r$ hardly equals $-0.5$.

Comment: Possible value of $p+q$, $q+r$ is $0,1,2・・・$.

Comment: Oh my bad! I was confusing integers with real numbers!

Comment: Please don’t include important parts of your question as images. They are neither searchable nor accessible to people with screen readers.

Comment: I don't know if this will help you, but Archimedes showed that area of the parabolic segment PQR is to area of the trianagle PQR as 4/3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two solutions of the equation $xy=-1$ over the integers, because both $x$ and $y$ are divisors of $1$, i.e., $\pm 1$. So we have $(x,y)=(1,-1)$ and $(-1,1)$. The reason is that the unit group of $\mathbb{Z}$ is $\{ \pm 1\}$.

If $p,q,r$ are integers, so are $x=q+r$ and $y=p+q$.